# when i change the language of app i want clipboard text (Copy, Paste etc.,) to english only in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

*this is my main.dart my problem is when I switch the language of the app I want the  (Copy, Paste, etc.,) to be only English. for example, when I change it to the Arabic language I want the clipboard text (Copy, Paste, etc.,) to remain in the English language. i triend alot but not found any solution *

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pir_zakat/screens/AboutUsScreen.dart';
import 'package:pir_zakat/screens/SettingScreen.dart';
import 'package:pir_zakat/screens/loading_screen.dart';
import 'localization/zakat_localization.dart';
import 'screens/first_part_screen.dart';
import 'screens/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:pir_zakat/Utilites/constants.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static void setLocal(BuildContext context, Locale locale) {
    _MyAppState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();
    state.setLocal(locale);
  }

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale _locale = Locale('fa', 'IR');

  void setLocal(Locale newLocal) {
    setState(() {
      _locale = newLocal;
      print('new local is ${newLocal.languageCode}');
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    getLocale().then((local) {
      setState(() {
        this._locale = local;
      });
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_locale == null) {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        locale: Locale('de'),
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
          ZakatLocalization.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('fa', 'IR'), // Hebrew
          Locale('en', 'US'), // English
          Locale('ar', 'SA'), // Hebrew

          // ... other locales the app supports
        ],
        localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales) {
          for (var local in supportedLocales) {
            if (local.languageCode == deviceLocale.languageCode &&
                local.countryCode == deviceLocale.countryCode) {
              return deviceLocale;
            }
          }
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
        initialRoute: LoadingScreen.id,
        routes: {
          LoadingScreen.id: (context) => LoadingScreen(),
          FirstPartScreen.id: (context) => FirstPartScreen(),
          SettingString.id: (context) => SettingString(),
          AboutUsScreen.id: (context) => AboutUsScreen(),
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer resting from all this effort and use ready made plugin like [localize_and_translate](https://pub.dev/packages/localize_and_translate)

anyway, what you need is to use key for the main widget class and request a new one or something so you restart you app for everything to take effect in place and you need to add iOS delegates also

take a look at how the [plugin source code](https://github.com/msayed-net/localize_and_translate) manage things, and you should get it, it creates `LocalizedApp` class which includes restart method for requesting new key for main widget class within `LocalizedApp` and that gets the magic done